# MySQL retrieve data for the past 24 hours when the column table is of type date NOT timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data for the passed 24 hours but I am getting nothing, but when I check on the table column (days) directly in db, I can find them. Here is my query:

```
select * from mytable
where
days between concat(date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`between` requires 2 arguments that specify the range:

```
select * from mytable
where days between date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) and now();
```

Or simply

```
select * from mytable
where days > date_sub(now(), interval 1 day);
```

Comment: my mistake was i that i was focusing on using between the second query saved my time. thanks @Honza

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
select * from mytable where days > date_sub(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```